# USing (MVC) ASP.NET's built in user management with a custom server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have been trying to grasp ASP.NET MVC recently and I am having some difficulty with the built in user management.

The system (out of the box) as able to manage user creation and makes limiting access to ActionResults really simple.

I would like a little more control over the ASP.NET database...
So I have a SQL Server where I am collecting and storing information from forms on the site and I have run aspnet_regsql on this server with no problem.

Despite changing the connection string in Web.config and modifying the default server in Visual Studio's data connections- users are still being created in a Visual Studio generated database.

How do I point Visual Studio's .NET user management to the database "aspnetdb" that regsql created?

Comment: Assuming your solution is using Entity Framework, search for 'dbcontext' within your solution.  If you're using code first, you should be able to specify the name of the connection within the constructor.

Comment: Are you referring to ": base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)" where DefaultConnection is the connection string in WebConfig?

Comment: Yup, that's the one.  Is the connection string that you want to use (that refers to the correct database) called `DefaultConnection` in the web.config?  If not, put the name of the correct connection string instead of `DefaultConnection`

Comment: So I have changed  "<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString" to the correct connection string and it is still not working... There are no errors though. Also, notably, I made sure to create a new project just to be scientific about it...

Comment: Sounds good to me

Comment: For some reason the information is still not showing up in my database yet I can login with a newly registered user, which tells me it is still defaulting to the VS server...

Comment: Make sure that you're editing the config file that is marked as your startup solution.  This is the one that will be being read from by your DbContext.